# Xcode with fortran

Tags: xcode, gfortran

I'm trying to compile some fortran files in Xcode, using a makefile made by me. The problem is that Xcode can't find gfortran compiler. I have it, because if I go to console and try to compile from there it works well.

Do you know how to add fortran compiler to Xcode.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [gfortran](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran) compiler (binaries for Mac available [here](http://hpc.sourceforge.net/)) along with the XCode gfortran plugin, available [there](http://www.macresearch.org/xcode_gfortran_plugin_update).

Answer (score 2):

The Xcode gfortran plugin does not work with the latest version of Xcode (3.2 I believe).